# Ajax XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have js code as well as *.txt file with some text that I want to load to the page.

**JS Code:**

```
 (function () {
 var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
 link.onclick = function () {
      var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304)) {
                xhr.responseText;
                var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                var pText = document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText);
                p.appendChild(pText);
                body.appendChild(p);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("Get", "ajax.txt", true);
        hxr.send(null);
        return false;
    };
})();
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<body>
<h1>AjaxTest</h1>
<a href="ajax.txt">Load the text from file</a>
<script src="main.js">
</script>
```

Everything should work. However ReSharper underlines **XmlHttpRequest();** and says **Use of an implicitly declared global variable"** and for this **xhr.responseText;** it says - **Expression statement is not assignment of call.**
What is the problem?

Comment: If you run the code, which error do you get? [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

- Capitalize "XML":

  `var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();` -> `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

- A variable is not a statement:

  `xhr.responseText;`, just get rid of this line, it's like saying `var a = 5;` and then `a;`

- You can use `document.body` to get the body element:

  `var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];` ->

  `var body = document.body;`

- You have no variable named `hxr`:

  `hxr.send(null);` -> `xhr.send(null);`

If you're following this is what you should get:

```
 (function () {
 var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
 link.onclick = function () {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304)) {
                var body = document.body;
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                var pText = document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText);
                p.appendChild(pText);
                body.appendChild(p);
            }
        };
        xhr.open("Get", "ajax.txt", true);
        xhr.send(null);
        return false;
    };
})();
```

If I were you I'd prefer **using jQuery:**

```
$('a').first().click(function() {
    $.get('ajax.txt', function(data) {
        $(document.body).append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
    });
});
```

**This is your entire code using jquery ;)**

Comment: Thanx but I still have the error message  - Name XMLHttpRequest does not match rule 'Constructor'.Suggested name is XmlHttpRequest I think this is due to the Resharper.